# How to enable shortcuts in child form

Tags: c#, .net

I have wrote a frame application, it's a windows form app as parent form.When it starts, it will find dlls in /modules and load them as extensions. And when I click the menuItem in the parent form, the specific dll will work.If the dll is a Form app, it will show.But when i try to use shortcuts(only build-ins,eg : CTRL-C...) in the childForm ,the hotkeys does not work. Anyone kindly tell me why and how can i fix the issue? Here's my code:

```
//parent.exe--ModuleEntrance.cs
public abstract class ModuleEntrance {
  public abstract string[] GetMenuNames();
  public abstract string[] GetMenuItemNames();
  public abstract EventHandler[] GetEventHandlers();
}
//parent.exe--ParentForm.cs
public partial class MDIParent : Form {
  public MDIParent() { //CTOR
    InitializeComponent();
    ModuleEntrance oneEntrance;
    string oneMenuName, oneMenuItemName;
    ToolStripMenuItem theMenu, theMenuItem;
    for(){ //iterate dlls in /modules, if it implement ModuleEntrance, load it. 
          //And 1)load menu&menuItem.  
          //2) connect handler to menuItem.click through 
        //<code:theMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(oneEntrance.GetEventHandlers()[i]);>
    }
}

//--------------
//child.dll-- EntranceImp.cs  //implement AC
public class EntranceImp : ModuleEntrance {
  public override string[] GetMenuNames() {
    return new string[] { "MENU"};
  }
  public override string[] GetMenuItemNames() {
    return new string[] { "OpenChildForm"};
  }
  public override EventHandler[] GetEventHandlers() {
    return new EventHandler[]{
      (EventHandler)delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { //Anonymous method
        childForm form = new childForm();
        //find MDIparent and connect them
        ToolStripMenuItem mi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        form.MdiParent = (Form)(mi.OwnerItem.Owner.Parent);  //It works!
        form.Show();
      }
    };
  }
}
//child.dll--childForm.dll
//...
```

Comment: The code that doesn't work is not in the snippet.  No sign of an assignment to the ShortcutKeys property.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I have already set the EnableShortcuts propers in childform.What I want is just make windows build-in hotkeys(ctr-c,ctrl-x,ctrl-v) works ,not user defined hotkeys. I give the code snippet because i think i use a ugly and odd method to connect child and MDIparent.Maybe because this, the problem comes.

Comment: Does the child form have event handlers for the hotkeys, or do you expect the parent to be able to catch the hotkeys?  If you expect the parent form to catch the hotkeys, you need to either relay the key events from the child to the parent or to use a hook to catch keypresses (using dllimport).

Comment: I think ctrl-c, ctrl-x, ctrl-v are still considered user shortcuts, not system shortcuts...  Those shortcuts are only built into some controls.  A WinForm by itself would not know what to do with those shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks all.Excuse me,perhaps I mislead you. What i want is to catch hotkeys(ctrl-c,ctrl-v)in a textbox inside childform.NOT want childForm to response the hotkeys. Hope you kindly forgive me for my poor English.Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child form has to notify the parent form about the key-down events somehow.

A way to do this is to have the child form expose key-down events that the parent form can listen to.  Remember to remove the parent event handlers every time that you change child form, or you'll end up with a memory leak since objects are not garbage collected until you release all references to them, including event handlers.

```
class Parent
{
    KeyEventHandler KeyDownHandler;

    public Parent()
    {
        KeyDownHandler = new KeyEventHandler(form_TextBoxKeyDown);
    }

    void SetChildForm(Child form)
    {
        form.TextBoxKeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
    }

    void RemoveChildForm(Child form)
    {
        form.TextBoxKeyDown -= KeyDownHandler;
    }

    void form_TextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.C:

                    break;
                case Keys.X:

                    break;
                case Keys.V:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Child
{
    TextBox txtBox;

    public event KeyEventHandler TextBoxKeyDown;

    internal Child()
    {
        txtBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtBox_KeyDown);
    }

    void txtBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxKeyDown != null)
            TextBoxKeyDown(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But I want to know what's your code's intention? When childform catch keydown event,it will call a event handlers defined in the parentForm.  en....I think iam too dull to know the key point of the code.

Comment: @user622851:  I think you got the keypoint:  "When childform catch keydown event,it will call a event handlers defined in the parentForm. "  I don't think there is any other way to relay the keydown information to the parent form otherwise.  You want to handle keydown information to handle the ctr-c, ctrlx, etc shortcuts, right?